# Plot in pycharm sciview is different from the output plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am using the Pycharm interpreter to make plots. However, the plots show in the Sciview is different from the output plots I have saved  after I updated the  Pycharm to the newest version. I cannot use Sciview to modify the plot as it is not the exact plot I am trying to make. Can someone help me to solve the problem please? Thank you in advance.

Jay

[image: plot in Sciview]
[image: output plot]